# How do I resolve the force due to gravity into components on a “3D incline?”

Tags: calculus, physics

So I know that for an object on an incline in 2 dimensions, the expressions for the forces of gravity and friction respectively would look like this:

$F_g = mg$ where g is the acceleration due to gravity on earth, $-9.81 m s^{-2}$

The components of that vector on a new coordinate plane using the surface of the incline as the *x*-axis would be $mg\sin(\theta)$ and $mg\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle of the incline from the horizontal/ground.

$F_f = \mu mg\cos(\theta)$ where $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction between the incline and the object.

**But how do I do that in 3 dimensions?**

For a project I’m doing, I need to formulate an expression for the net force on an object that lies on a 3-dimensional surface and I’m not entirely sure how to go about that.

I imagine the process used in 2 dimensions could be extended to work something like spherical polar coordinates in 3D since the 2D force components are of the form $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$.

The 3-dimensional surface I’m working with will not have a constant slope so I’m guessing I’d have to work out $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ at that point and then resolve the force vector for gravity using the definitions that allow one to convert from 3D Cartesian to spherical polar:

$x$-component: $mg\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$

$y$-component: $mg\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$

$z$-component: $mg\sin(\phi)$

Is that technically correct? Are there more efficient or overall better ways of going about it?

Answer (score 1):

Choose your coordinate system to have a plane(say $xy$) defined by the vertical direction and the normal to the plane at the point where you can find your mass $m$ at $t=0$. In the plane your motion is similar to what you had before. **In the direction perpendicular to this plane you have no forces** (no gravity and no normal force), so the acceleration in this $z$ direction is $0$, or $v_z=v_z(t=0)$